# Is it possible to put a password to let usb debugging work?

Tags: usb-debugging, privacy, broken-screen, password-protection

So, I learned that, if we have a broken screen, but had the usb debugging enabled, we could do a lot of things, and even use its apps from a desktop computer, until we can get it properly fixed.

But, also, if my phone gets stolen it just sounds like doom to me...

The alternative I thought was: keep usb debugging enabled, but limit it completely, requiring some kind of password or trick to let everything else work.

Is it possible to do that? and how?

I understand this question complements [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/89043/is-there-any-way-to-put-a-password-to-avoid-someone-from-hard-resetting-my-phone).

Comment: USB Debugging requires you to press "Allow" once you plug your phone in to a computer your phone doesn't recognise. You could also encrypt your entire phone if your're concerned someone will get your data. That's what I do.

Comment: @Janekmuric you are right, it is the 1st time I try it on my new phone, I think the old android phone didnt require it, may be this question is only still valid for old android versions? because it is already safer on new androids, thx! (good I had to activate it after this!)

Comment: Yes. Old android versions don't require you to press allow, so the only way to fix this is to completely disable USB debugging. But then again, if someone steals your old phone, it probably doesn't have the feature to be encrypted.